# Groovy sh command is not including quotes in my echo command

Tags: linux, shell, groovy, escaping

I am trying to write `hostname` within quotes to a file. And I am doing this in a Groovy script. Here is my sh Groovy script.

```
sh "echo Add \"my-hostname\" \"$HOSTNAME\" >> /etc/test.conf"
```

My expected outcome in `/etc/test.conf` should be:

```
Add "my-hostname" "linux-base"
```

But when I execute my Groovy script the outcome is:

```
Add my-hostname linux-base
```

Somebody please help me in `sh` command script.

Comment: Try this way of [add double quotes](http://glu.977617.n3.nabble.com/Add-double-quotes-in-a-string-in-groovy-script-td4026207.html) .

Answer (score 1):

Two workarounds:

1. Use single quotes:

   ```
   sh 'echo Add \"my-hostname\" \"'"$HOSTNAME"'\" >> aa'
   ```
2. Use double escaping:

   ```
   sh "echo Add \\\"my-hostname\\\" \\\"$HOSTNAME\\\" >> aa"
   ```

I am not familiar with groovy, are you sure your command doesn't need `sh -c`?